# Saving SVG with transparent background in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, transparency, image-format

How can I save an SVG file in Inkscape with a transparent background?

I've tried setting `File > Document properties > Background color > Set the alpha channel to 0`, but the resulting file has a white background when uploaded to my printer's website.

Comment: Is your printer's website supposed to show transparency differently?

Comment: Are you uploading as a PDF by chance? I've seen issues in the past where PDF files generated by Inkscape didn't appropriately show transparency when rendering a preview on sites like VistaPrint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inkscape's default is to save SVGs without any background, unless you added one.

Try dragging your SVG into a raster image editor like GIMP or Photoshop. You'll soon find out if it really has a background or not. If it does, then either you added it, or your printer's website has done something to the image.

Here's a screenshot of a basic SVG, a circle with a fill and stroke, created in Inkscape, with default settings, and opened directly in GIMP. There is no background. The same is possible with Photohsop.

[image: Inkscape SVG opened in GIMP with transparent background]

Here is the link to download this SVG if you want to try it yourself. http://www.filedropper.com/test_305

Answer (score -1):

I don't really use Inkscape but you can solve it in other way, just open the svg file with your favorite text editor and set `fill="none"` or try `opacity="0"`.

option 1: `<rect  x="27" y="115" width="43" height="40" stroke="#979797" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></rect>`

option 2: `<rect  x="27" y="115" width="43" height="40" stroke="#979797" stroke-width="2" fill="#ffcc00" opacity="0"></rect>`

Good luck!

Comment: That's assuming the SVG has a rect for a background that *also has a stroke*. Otherwise just delete the whole path